# How to show errors from ChangeNotifier using Provider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-provider, provider-model

I'm trying to find the best way to show errors from a Change Notifier Model with Provider through a Snackbar.

Is there any built-in way or any advice you could help me with?

I found this way that is working but I don't know if it's correct.

Suppose I have a simple Page where I want to display a list of objects and a Model where I retrieve those objects from api. In case of error I notify an error String and I would like to display that error with a SnackBar.

## page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Page extends StatefulWidget {
  Page({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageState createState() => _PageState();
}

class _PageState extends State< Page > {

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    Provider.of<Model>(context, listen: false).load();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    Provider.of< Model >(context, listen: false).addListener(_listenForErrors);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Consumer<Model>(
          builder: (context, model, child){
  
            if(model.elements != null){
              ...list
            }
            else return LoadingWidget();
          }
        )
      )
    );
  }



  void _listenForErrors(){
    final error = Provider.of<Model>(context, listen: false).error;
    if (error != null) {
      Scaffold.of(context)
        ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
        ..showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
            content: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.error),
                Expanded(child: Padding( padding:EdgeInsets.only(left:16), child:Text(error) )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() { 
        Provider.of<PushNotificationModel>(context, listen: false).removeListener(_listenForErrors);
    super.dispose();
  }

}
```

## page_model.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class BrickModel extends ChangeNotifier {

  List<String> _elements;
  List<String> get elements => _elements;

  String _error;
  String get error => _error;

  Future<void> load() async {
    try{
      final elements = await someApiCall();
      _elements = [..._elements, ...elements];
    }
    catch(e) {
      _error = e.toString();
    }
    finally {
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: I was facing this exact same problem yesterday. I couldn't come up with a clean way to display snackbars when using provider.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit 2022**

I ported (and reworked) this package also for river pod if anyone is interested

https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod_messages/versions/1.0.0

**EDIT 2020-06-05**

I developed a slightly better approach to afford this kink of situations.

It can be found at [This repo on github](https://github.com/quantosapplications/flutter_provider_utilities) so you can see the implementation there, or use this package putting in your pubspec.yaml

```
 provider_utilities:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/quantosapplications/flutter_provider_utilities.git
```

So when you need to present messages to the view you can:

1. extend your `ChangeNotifier` with `MessageNotifierMixin` that gives your `ChangeNotifier` two properties, `error` and `info`, and two methods, `notifyError()` and `notifyInfo()`.
2. Wrap your Scaffold with a MessageListener that will present a Snackbar when it gets called notifyError() or NotifyInfo()

I'll give you an example:

**ChangeNotifier**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider_utilities/provider_utilities.dart';

class MyNotifier extends ChangeNotifier with MessageNotifierMixin {

  List<String> _properties = [];
  List<String> get properties => _properties;

  Future<void> load() async {

    try {
      /// Do some network calls or something else
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), (){

        _properties = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];
        notifyInfo('Successfully called load() method');

      });
    }
    catch(e) {
      notifyError('Error calling load() method');
    }

  }

}
```

**View**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider_utilities/provider_utilities.dart';

import 'notifier.dart';

class View extends StatefulWidget {
  View({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ViewState createState() => _ViewState();
}

class _ViewState extends State<View> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: MessageListener<MyNotifier>(
        child: Selector<MyNotifier, List<String>>(
          selector: (ctx, model) => model.properties,
          builder: (ctx, properties, child) => ListView.builder(
            itemCount: properties.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => ListTile(
              title: Text(properties[index])
            ),
          ),
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

thank you.

Maybe I found a simpler way to handle this, using the powerful property "child" of Consumer.

With a custom stateless widget (I called it ErrorListener but it can be changed :))

```
class ErrorListener<T extends ErrorNotifierMixin> extends StatelessWidget {

  final Widget child;

  const ErrorListener({Key key, @required this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<T>(
      builder: (context, model, child){
        
        //here we listen for errors
        if (model.error != null) { 
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
             _handleError(context, model); });
        }

        // here we return child!
        return child;
      },
      child: child
    );
  }


  // this method will be called anytime an error occurs
  // it shows a snackbar but it could do anything you want
  void _handleError(BuildContext context, T model) {
    Scaffold.of(context)
    ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
    ..showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[600],
        content: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.error),
            Expanded(child: Padding( padding:EdgeInsets.only(left:16), child:Text(model.error) )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

    // this will clear the error on model because it has been handled
    model.clearError();
  }
}
```

This widget must be put under a scaffold if you want to use a snackbar.

I use a mixin here to be sure that model has a `error` property and a `clarError()` method.

```
mixin ErrorNotifierMixin on ChangeNotifier {
  String _error;
  String get error => _error;

  void notifyError(dynamic error) {
    _error = error.toString();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void clearError() {
    _error = null;
  }
}
```

So for example we can use this way

```
class _PageState extends State<Page> {

   // ...

@override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      builder: (context) => MyModel(),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: ErrorListener<MyModel>(
          child: MyBody()
        )
      )
    );

}
```

Comment: That's a nice approach! Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: I like this approach, but what about if I use MultiProvider? That would changes a lot or not?

Comment: @IgnacioGiagante I currently use this with MultiProvider and there's no problem about that. You can listen to one or more changenotifiers wrapping your scaffold with the listener. I developed a slightly better version of this approach that you can find in https://github.com/quantosapplications/flutter_provider_utilities. You can extend ChangeNotifier with MessageNotifierMixin that gives you notifyError and notifyInfo methods. Than you can wrap a Scaffold with MessageListener that will listen and present a snacker when you notify error or info

Comment: Have you considered publishing this as a package on pub.dev

Answer (score 7):

You can create a custom `StatelessWidget` to launch the snackbar when the view model changes. For example:

```dart
class SnackBarLauncher extends StatelessWidget {
  final String error;

  const SnackBarLauncher(
      {Key key, @required this.error})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (error != null) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
          (_) => _displaySnackBar(context, error: error));
    }
    // Placeholder container widget
    return Container();
  }

  void _displaySnackBar(BuildContext context, {@required String error}) {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(error));
    Scaffold.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

We can only display the snackbar once all widgets are built, that's why we have the `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()` call above.

Now we can add `SnackBarLauncher` to our screen:

```
class SomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Title',
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          // Other widgets here...

          Consumer<EmailLoginScreenModel>(
            builder: (context, model, child) =>
                SnackBarLauncher(error: model.error),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```